# Treat a created_at date as a date instead of a time for formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, I have the following configuration for date formats:

**config/initializers/time_formats.rb**

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:concise] = "%d/%b/%Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:concise] = "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M %Z"
```

In my view, if I do:

```
MODEL.created_at.to_formatted_s(:concise)
```

... it correctly picks-up the `:concise` format for the `datetime` date type, and renders it as follows:

13/Oct/2020 05:00 UTC

Note that the `%b` is the short Month name - Oct in this case. If I only want to show the date, I would assume that I'd simply use the `to_date` method to convert the `datetime` to a `date` first:

```
MODEL.created_at.to_date.to_formatted_s(:concise)
```

This does render a date, but it doesn't pick up the `:concise` date format properly. It renders:

13/10/2020

Note it's not rendering October as 10, instead of formatting as `%b`. I've tried adding a `:default` date type in time_formats.rb but that didn't fix it.

Why is this happening just for the **Date** type?

(I'm using ruby 2.5.8, Rails 6.)

Comment: Have you looked into using localization for this, by updating the `en.yml` file and using `i18n.l`... https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats

Comment: I can't reproduce your results with Rails 6 running 2.5.8 (or 2.7.1). Converting to ``Date`` works as you expect, so something else is going on.

Comment: This seems like an excessively complicated way of doing `MODEL.created_at.strftime("%d/%b/%Y %H:%M %Z")`

Comment: @rmlockerd thanks for testing. I just realized what was going on. The `config/initializers/time_formats.rb` file only seems to be read when the Rails server is restarted. I had changed the configuration for the `date` format in it, but didn't know that I had to restart the server for it to take effect.